# SharePoint 2016 Search 404 Error and SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, 2016, sharepoint-search

We are on SharePoint 2016 Server.

I am receiving a message when I try to search "Unexpected response from server. The status code of response is '404'. The status text of response is 'Not Found'."

I also receive a "Sorry, we're having trouble reaching the server" message when I try to grant someone permissions to the site.

Our Search Service Application is running in Central Administration. I do not see any errors.

Also when we use SharePoint Designer 2013 we receive a message that says SharePoint Foundation not installed.

Could someone please help with suggestions.

[image: Search Working]
[image: Search not working]
[image: Unlisted File Extensions]

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

See a post with similar issue here: [Search Error - 404 Not Found.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51797/search-error-404-not-found) It seems that your SharePoint installation is missing fundamental components or patches and identified as incomplete.

I would suggest you check the ULS logs/System Event Viewer for detailed error message on this issue.

Also, run the SharePoint Configuration Wizard again to see if there is any error in this process.

Comment: Ok I will check out the event logs and I will run the Configuration Wizard. I wanted to point out that I think there is an IIS STIG that we have to follow that is causing the issue. When I uncheck the Allow unlisted file extensions option" I have issues. See images of search working and not working. When the option is checked everything seems to work.
Unlisted file extensions in URL requests must be filtered by any IIS 8.5 website.  https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/iis_8.5_site/2018-01-03/finding/V-76827

Comment: @Kevin that will be a problem.  SharePoint requires that to work, as you have discovered.  (It also fails to install if you have enabled FIPS compliance).

Comment: @Greg W yes we experienced many frustrating issues with FIPS. We were able to present some documentation to our organization and as a results we were able to disable the System cryptography: Use FIPS compliant algorithms for encryption, hashing, and signing local security policy on our SharePoint Servers.

Comment: @Greg W thanks for your response. Do you have any information on why Allow unlisted file extensions should be checked? I have it unchecked at the server level but I have it checked at the site level. I am not sure what file extension should be allowed in order for search to work? Any info anyone has will be helpful.

Comment: @Kevin not on hand.  I take the stance that SharePoint creates the WebSite in IIS and configures it as needed (ignoring TLS certificates) and it shouldn’t be touched.  It’s set it that way for a reason and just “because it feels like it”.

Comment: Sorry, that should be 'It's set it that way for a reason and *NOT* just "because it feels like it"'

Comment: Ok thanks Greg W and Chelsea_MSFT. I ran the SharePoint Configuration Wizard via powershell this morning and I am not seeing any errors. @Chelsea_MSFT do you have any other suggestions? Seems like it is the Allow Unlisted File Extensions causing the issue.

Comment: @Kevin Agree with Greg W on this, I think you should keep the settings in IIS untouched. But in case anything helps, see a post with similar issue here: https://serverfault.com/questions/396229/what-file-extensions-must-be-allowed-in-request-filtering-when-using-asp-net-mvc